# I am getting this error 'get_HistoryInfos' in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am getting this error.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Method
>   'get_HistoryInfos' in type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper' from
>   assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' does not have an
>   implementation.

My website is on web Hosting and it was running fine.This error is coming from last 2 days. please guide me if anyone has encountered this error.

Comment: have a look at [TypeLoadException: Method 'get_HistoryInfos' does not have an implementation - revisited](https://answers.sap.com/questions/408789/typeloadexception-method-get-historyinfos-does-not.html) it might help.